# Unity Mathf.Clamp issue on mobile

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I use this code:

```
    void Update () {
    if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Desktop) 
    {
        float xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        this.rb.velocity = new Vector2(xMovement, 0) * this.speed;


    } else if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Handheld) 
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            if (touch.position.x > this.westTouchBound && touch.position.x < this.eastTouchBound) 
            {

            } else 
            {
                this.speed = this.ballRigidBody.velocity.magnitude * 2.0f;

                Vector3 location = this.gameCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);

                Vector3 delta = location - this.transform.position;
                Vector2 course = new Vector2(delta.x, 0.0f);
                course.Normalize();
                this.rb.velocity = course * speed;

            }

        } else 
        {
            this.rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }

    }
    float eastMax = this.gameController.screenWidth / 2.0f - this.gameController.wallThickness - this.gameController.barWidth / 2.0f;
    float westMax = -eastMax;

    float actualX = Mathf.Clamp(this.transform.position.x, westMax, eastMax);
    this.transform.position = new Vector3(actualX, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);

}
```

On mac it works just fine, but on iOS or Android bar just bounces of the boundary and after that gets back and it looks horrible. I studied logs and it seems that the problem is in physics, looks like PC treats it in some kind of different way than mobile. I have tried a lot of stuff, moving code to FixedUpdate, LateUpdate, tried to change controls, even tried assign rigidbody position and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into something like this before,

just replace this

```
float actualX = Mathf.Clamp(this.transform.position.x, westMax, eastMax);
```

with this

```
if(actualX < westMax)
{
    actualX = westMax;
}
else if(actualX > eastMax)
{
    actualX = eastMax;
}
```

looks like clamp is broken or something

Comment: This does not work. I think an issue is somewhere in physics.